# woocommerce email template preview shows in plain text instead in html

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

In **`WooCommerce`** > **`Settings`** > **`Emails`** there is a section **`"Email Template"`** with the following text:

"This section lets you customize the WooCommerce emails. Click here to preview your email template."

When I click on the link, preview shows in plain text, not HTML.

Does anyone have an idea how can I make it show in html format?

Basic server info and WP info:

```
centOs 7
WC Version: 2.6.11
WP version: 4.7
Server Info: nginx/1.10.2
PHP Version: 5.4.16
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this same setting page (within this "emails" setting tab), you have just before the list of all available notification. You need first to "configure" settings for each notification changing **`content/type`** from **`text/plain`** to **`text/html`** (or **`multipart/alternative`** for both of them).

For example for **complete order email notification**:

[image]

Then "Save changes" …

Comment: great... all templates already were marked as HTML, but another "save" was missing. Thanks!